# How do I add to this Collection in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, api

I'm pulling some data down in a REST API from our ITSM solution, it gets parsed from json and put into an object called $listOfCurrentUsers. I'm then creating an object from data that I pull from Active Directory. It then checks to see if the AD user exists in the $listOfCurrentUsers and if it does, it adds the record ID to the $CAServiceDesk object. If the user doesn't exist, it still adds the record ID, but gives it a value of null.

```
$listOfCurrentUsers = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $getList -Header $requestHeader

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$CAServiceDesk = Get-ADGroupMember "ServiceDesk" -Recursive |
ForEach-Object(
{
    Get-ADUser($_.samaccountname) -Properties * | 
        Select-Object -Property Name,
            @{Name = 'SAM Account Name'; Expression = {$_.samaccountname}},
            Department,
            @{Name = 'Telephone Number'; Expression = {$_.telephonenumber}},
            @{Name = 'Manager'; Expression = {($_.manager -split ',*..=')[1]}},
            @{Name = 'User Account Control'; Expression = {$_.useraccountcontrol}},
            Mail,
            @{Name = 'Employee ID'; Expression = {$_.employeeID}}

    if($listOfCurrentUsers.users | where { $_.PublicID -eq $CAServiceDesk.Name }) {
        Add-Member -InputObject  -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RecID -Value $_.RecordID}   
    else {
        Add-Member -InputObject  -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RecID -Value {"null"}}

}
)
```

I'm stuck on the "if true then this" section. I can't seem to figure out how to assign the RecordID value to the Add-Member?

Comment: this >>> `{ $_.RecordID eq` <<< is missing the closing brace ... and would only give you a `[bool]`, not the value. you otta be able to use just >>> `$_.RecordID` <<< to put just the value from that property into the new property. ///// are you SURE that you are modifying the correct object? you are adding a prop to the _current object_ using `$_` ... and that is already the current object.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure if I'm modifying the correct object, what I want is to add the RecID field from $listOfCurrentUsers to $CAServiceDesk when there's a match. Otherwise it should add the RecID member to $CAServiceDesk with a value of null.

Comment: it looks like Bacon Bits has you covered. he also saw the glitch in your pipeline and seems to have worked around it. ///// i would have NOT used a pipeline so that i could directly access all the properties of each returned item, but that is just my pref for easy-to-debug code. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't seem valid. You're either missing a closing brace for the first ForEach-Object or you're using `$CAServiceDesk` inside the expression that assigns a value to `$CAServiceDesk` (i.e., it's going to be an empty variable when you call it).

However, if I make my best guess at what you're doing and what the objects look like, I would write this like so:

```
# This should give you a hash table that maps PublicID to RecordID.
# This will not work as I expect if PublicID can be duplicated.
$TableOfCurrentUsers = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $getList -Header $requestHeader |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty users |
    Select-Object -Property PublicID, RecordID |
    Group-Object -Property PublicID -AsHashTable

# This will get the users and build your custom object
$CAServiceDesk = Get-ADGroupMember "ServiceDesk" -Recursive |
    Get-ADUser -Properties Name, SamAccountName, Department, TelephoneNumber, Manager, UserAccountControl, Mail, EmployeeID |
    Select-Object -Property Name,
        @{n = 'SAM Account Name'; e = {$_.samaccountname}},
        Department,
        @{n = 'Telephone Number'; e = {$_.telephonenumber}},
        @{n = 'Manager'; e = {($_.manager -split ',*..=')[1]}},
        @{n = 'User Account Control'; e = {$_.useraccountcontrol}},
        Mail,
        @{n = 'Employee ID'; e = {$_.employeeID}},
        @{n = 'RecID'; e = { $TableOfCurrentUsers[$_.Name] }}
```

Note that you should never specify `Get-ADUser -Properties *` unless you really, really need to. Some of the properties are quite long, and it will make your LDAP queries take quite a long time.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the Get-ADUser function. Unfortunately this didn't work, it didn't add the RecID field, also I'm not sure how this would work if the user doesn't already exist in the ITSM system, how would it add the null field? I fixed my original code, I guess I didn't scroll down for enough on the copy/paste. I'm honestly not sure if any of the Add-Member code is correct, I'm kind of stuck though.

Comment: @JasonWaldeck What didn't work? The first statement, or the second? What errors did you get? What results do you get?

Comment: The first statement did work, the second one though did not add the RecID property to the object, when I displayed it, that property is missing.

Comment: Apologies, I was missing something on the AD query, it does create the RecID Property, but it's blank.

Comment: The hash table that's created in the first statement looks correct, if I look at it I get: 
   Key   : Jason.Waldeck
   Value : {@{publicId=Jason.Waldeck; 
   recordId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}}
   Name  : Jason.Waldeck

However the second part, the RecID field is blank.